# How to disable "Random page" in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Surprisingly enough, I have a problem finding a solution to this—I want to disable / remove the Random page link from a MediaWiki wiki on the left bar.

I think it is hard to find the answer on Google because "Random page" appears in many wikis as the actual link for Random page, but maybe I am googling for the wrong thing.

I couldn't find anything in `LocalSettings.php` either.

Answer (score 5):

The code for the sidebar is in the page `MediaWiki:Sidebar`. It should be enough to remove the line `** randompage-url|randompage` from there. You need administrative privileges to edit that page.

Note that this does not actually disable the “Random page” feature (that's still accessible from `Special:Random`), it just removes the link from the sidebar. If you want to remove it altogether, you can add the following code to your LocalSettings.php:

```
function disableSpecialRandom(&$list) {
        unset($list['Random']);
        return true;
}
$wgHooks['SpecialPage_initList'][]='disableSpecialRandom';
```

Comment: I see. thanks. is it possible to remove it altogether?

Comment: You could do that by using the [`SpecialPage_initList` hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SpecialPage_initList).